# Where can I get a code review?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I know this may be a off-topic question, 
but I am trying to get better at coding.

At first, I was about to ask [a question about Sanitizing a Forum Post](http://pastebin.com/FMhd88ja). But I figured that question is just a code review of my approaches.

I am unsure if SO accept these question which are disguised as a "request for review".

Thus I ask if SO is an acceptable place to get my code reviewed and if not, where can I find one?

Comment: Not if it more than a screenful of code, and you must have a specific question about  a specific part of it.

Comment: How is this a meta question?

Comment: @Null Its because the OP is asking if its alright to post code and get it refractored by the community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's <del>an app</del> [a Stack Exchange beta site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Comment: This wasn't around in August was it?

Comment: I don't believe so, @Anraiki.

Answer (score 8):

SO is not really the right place for that.

Try [RefactorMyCode](http://www.refactormycode.com).

Comment: Thanks for the site. Now I can get my code reviewed :]

Comment: @Anraiki You are welcome. The question you posted there would be a good fit for SO though.

Comment: what about http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? just asking...